# Xamarin XAML ListView doesn't show when compiling

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I don't know why my list view is not showing up, I don't know if I need to add something, here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" BackgroundColor="#1B1B1B" x:Class="wantafood.Page1">
 <ContentPage.Content>


<ListView  x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="LabelText"
                            TextColor="#f35e20" />
                            <Label Text="LabelText2"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            TextColor="#503026" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

If someone could point to me what I'm missing, I would really appreciate that, I'm sure is something dumb, but I can't see it, thanks.

Comment: You need to set an ItemsSource

Comment: So, I cant do tests only using static items?

Comment: Of course you can. You can do it either in xaml (ListView.Items) or in code listView.Items.Add(object)

Comment: Thanks! the itemsource was the problem! now, Do you know how to separate each items? because there is no separation between them.

Comment: This is where ItemTemplate & ItemsPanel come in. Read about it [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/). While the link is talking about an ItemsControl, the same ideas apply for ListView as it's a derived control.